# Making tracking data available to Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, java, json

I have tracking data from GPS, which gives latitude, longitude, heading, etc.

Right now it's stored in a non-standard database (Accumulo) and I'm looking into how best to make the data available for Geoserver to be displayed using OpenLayers.

The data is not in any standard format either, it arrives as part of complex JSON files that report more information.

Essentially I have some text based lat/long data that I can put into anything, though I'd prefer to avoid using PostGIS if possible so I don't have to maintain two databases.

What are my options for getting the data into Geoserver?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this a lot (more than a couple of times) then you could write a custom datastore by following the steps in this [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) [tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/contentdatastore.html). Then all you need to do is drop the jar file into your WEB-INF/lib folder and it will work just like any other datastore in GeoServer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "Getting it into Geoserver" Do you want to display it on a WMS layer as a tile? What Client are you using?

Simplest way is to remove the items you don't want sent to the client from the JSON and just send the Json to the client and render it client side, assuming the client can read Json like OpenLayers can.

Geoserver can access a MySql Database, but if you want it Geo-referenced properly, you need to use PostGres with PostGis. Parse the Json File, put them into a PostGres Table with the postGis extensions, create a geometry column from the lat/lon text, point Geoserver at the table and you can serve your points to your client as a wms layer.

If they are from a GOPS, most likely the projection will be EPSG:4326 (WGS84)

Other options are to use shape files, etc but it is a lot more complicated.

Geoserver can also server Kml files if your client supports it or you want it to end up in Google Earth

Another BIG advantage is that you can style your layers and points using server side SLD and make them look very nice, all on the server.

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Convert the GeoJSON to Shapefile with some of the ogr tools, if you want to avoid PostgreSQL.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content - is there any chance that you could expand upon your answer in order to help both the asker and any future readers?